# How do I get the replies for each comment, in this Laravel app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have made a **blogging application in Laravel 8**.

The (single) article view displays comments under the article and I am now working on adding a **[comments reply functionality](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/49/files)** (link to the GitHub pull request with the current code).

In `app\Models\Comment.php` I have:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'article_id',
    'parent_id',
    'body',
    'approved'
  ];

  // Join users to comments
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  // Join articles to comments
  public function article() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
  }

  // Join comment replies to comments
  public function replies() {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
  }
}
```

The comment replies are those comments for wichb rhe `parent_id` column value is *not null*.

In the comments view (`comments-list.blade.php`) I have:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
  @if (null == $comment->parent_id)
    <li class="depth-1 comment">
      <div class="comment__avatar">
          <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </div>
      <div class="comment__content">
          <div class="comment__info">
              <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
              <div class="comment__meta">
                  <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
                  <div class="comment__reply">
                    <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment__text">
              <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')

      {{-- Comment replies --}}
      @if (count($comment->replies))
        <ul class="children">
          @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
            <li class="depth-2 comment">
              <div class="comment__avatar">
                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
              </div>
              <div class="comment__content">
                  <div class="comment__info">
                      <div class="comment__author">{{ $reply->user->first_name }} {{ $reply->user->last_name }}</div>
                      <div class="comment__meta">
                          <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($reply->created_at)) }}</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="comment__text">
                      <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      @endif
    </li>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

In the ArticlesController controller, I have the logic that displays a single article, with comments, if it has any :

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

  public function show( $slug ) {
    // Single article
    $article     = Article::firstWhere( 'slug', $slug );
    $old_article = Article::where( 'id', '<', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->first();
    $new_article = Article::where( 'id', '>', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'ASC' )->first();

    // Comments
    $commentsQuery  = $this->get_commentQuery( $article->id );
    $comments_count = $commentsQuery->count();

    // If infinite scroll, paginate comments (to be loaded one page per scroll),
    // Else show them all 

    if (boolval($this->is_infinitescroll)) {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate($this->comments_per_page);
    } else {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->get();
    }

    return view( 'themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single',
                 array_merge( $this->data, [
                   'categories'        => $this->article_categories,
                   'article'           => $article,
                   'old_article'       => $old_article,
                   'new_article'       => $new_article,
                   'comments'          => $comments,
                   'comments_count'    => $comments_count,
                   'comments_per_page' => $this->comments_per_page,
                   'tagline'           => $article->title,
                   'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
                 ] )
    );
  }

  /**
   * AJAX Call for Loading extra comments
   *
   * @param Request $request
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function get_comments_ajax( Request $request ) {
    if ( ! $request->ajax() ) {
      // Redirect to Home Page or just BOMB OUT!
      exit();
    }

    $more_comments_to_display = TRUE;

    /** @todo - 5 - This should\could be a setting */

    $article_id  = $request->post( 'article_id' );
    $page_number = $request->post( 'page' );
    $offset      = $this->comments_per_page * $page_number;

    $data['comments'] = $this->get_commentQuery( $article_id, $this->comments_per_page, $offset )->get();
    $content          = '';
    if ( $data['comments']->count() ) {
      $content .= view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/partials/comments-list',
                array_merge( $data, [
                  'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
                ])
      );
    } else {
      $more_comments_to_display = FALSE;
    }
    echo json_encode( [ 'html' => $content, 'page' => $page_number, 'more_comments_to_display' => $more_comments_to_display, 'article_id' => $article_id ] );
    exit();
  }

  /**
   * get_commentQuery
   *
   * @param int $article_id
   * @param int $limit
   * @param int $offset
   *
   * @return object
   */
  private function get_commentQuery( int $article_id, int $limit = 0, int $offset = 0 ): object {
    $commentQuery = Comment::where( [ 'article_id' => $article_id, 'approved' => 1 ] )->orderBy( 'id', $this->comments_orderby_direction );

    if ( $offset > 0 ) {
      $commentQuery = $commentQuery->offset( $offset );
    }
    if ( $limit > 0 ) {
      $commentQuery = $commentQuery->limit( $limit );
    }

    return $commentQuery;
  }

  public function add_comment( Request $request ) {
    $rules = [
      'msg' => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = [
      'msg.required' => 'Please enter a message'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );

    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
      return redirect()->back()
                       ->withErrors( $validator->errors() )
                       ->withInput()
                       ->with( 'error', 'Please correct the errors below );
    }

    $fields = $validator->validated();

    $comment = [
      'user_id'    => Auth::user()->id,
      'article_id' => $request->get( 'article_id' ),
      'parent_id' => $request->get( 'parent_id' ),
      'body'       => $fields['msg'],
      'approved'   => 0
    ];

    // Insert comment in the 'comments' table
    $query = Comment::create( $comment );

    if ( $query ) {
      return redirect()->back()->with( 'success', 'Your comment is pending.' );
    } else {
      return redirect()->back()->with( 'error', 'Adding comment failed' );
    }
  }
}
```

#### The problem

I have been unable to add the comment replies under each comment that has any.

The `$comment->replies` array is **empty for every comment** and (when the AJAX comments are enabled) I get the error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

#### Questions

1. Where is my mistake?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this problem?

Comment: add `$commentQuery = Comment::with('replies')`  and access `$comment->replies` and see

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Where should I add `$commentQuery = Comment::with('replies')`?

Comment: Can I see your comments and replies migration?

Comment: Have you verified the relationships are working, and there is data to show? Eg `php artisan tinker` and then check a comment and it's comment's replies? `$comment = Comment::find(1);`, and then `$comment->replies`;?

Comment: While adding a reply against a comment, have you checked the data in `$request->get( 'parent_id' )` ?

Comment: @linktoahref Yes, I did. The replies have all that is needed in the `comments` table. What is missing is their display.

Comment: I set up a new Laravel project, simplified versions of your model, added migrations, and inserted some test data both with plain SQL as well as with the relevant part of `add_comment()`.  Checking with `tinker`, I can see everything works as expected: `$comment->replies` shows the right set of replies for the selected comment.  [All code and Tinker transcripts here](https://pastebin.com/MCPjYghZ).  So it looks to me like the problem is in something you have not shown, the most obvious guess the data in the DB itself, or the migration, or the form which submits comments/replies.

Comment: I am assuming you have already debugged the various controller methods and they are all doing what you expect, eg `get_commentQuery()` works, `$comments` is really a collection of comments, including parents and children, `array_merge()` is working and whatever `$this->data` is is not clobbering your comments ... etc.

Comment: `$comment->repiles` return empty array because comment model's replies() method defines a relationship with itself. so, `$comment->replies` will only contain comments where the `parent_id` column matches the id of that comment instance.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Have a look at the **[pull request](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/49/files)** with the code I have so far. You can add to that branch or make a new one yourself if you want. I would love to have you as a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

**First Thing: (update following relation for replies)**

```
public function replies() {
 return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**Second Thing**

you must have to assign a clone of `get_commentQuery()` to multiple variables in order to get the correct `comments-count` and for comments list in separate queries. According to your logic `get_commentQuery()` method pointing to the same memory reference and first you manipulating that reference value by count query then applying fetch comments query ***(in short you are overriding the query by mistake so you need clone value to difference reference by `clone` keyword)***

Example Query would be like that:

```
   $tempQuery  = $this->get_commentQuery( $article->id );

   $commentsQuery = clone $tempQuery;
   $commentsCountQuery = clone $tempQuery;
```

**Third Thing (Eager load replies within the comment)**

while querying for `comment` you should have to eager load `replies` relations. So, in this way, each `comment` will have its all `replies` in its child relation:

Example:

```
$comments = $commentsQuery->with('replies')
```

If you don't understand anything then let me know:

Comment: There is no `replies` table. I have used **[this article](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-9-comment-system-example-tutorial)** as a guide.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Yes I know you are using the comment table for both purposes. For comments as well as replies using `parent_id`. For the comment your `parent_id` will be `null` and In case of `reply` its `parent_id` have comment `id`. If you see my first point I just define a relation with `replies` name and In its definition, I called the `Comment` modal. That approach called `recursive relation` or `parent-child relation`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir did you try my implementations?

Comment: Yes. Not working. Have a look at the pull request, it has all the current code.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir there are a few mistakes in it let me fix and I will push a pull request to you

Answer (score 0):

You can actually eager load a relationship from the relationship. In this situation, a recursive eager load is done:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'article_id',
    'parent_id',
    'body',
    'approved'
  ];

  // Join users to comments
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  // Join articles to comments
  public function article() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
  }

  // Join comment replies to comments
  public function replies() {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
  }

  // Join comment replies recursively to comments
  public function recursiveReplies() {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id')->with('recursiveReplies');
  }

  public function scopeByArticle($query, Article $article)
  {
      return $query->where('article_id', $article->id);   
  }
}
```

An other approach would be to add the `protected $with` property to the `Comment` model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'article_id',
    'parent_id',
    'body',
    'approved'
  ];

  protected $with = [
    'replies',
  ];

  // Join users to comments
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  // Join articles to comments
  public function article() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
  }

  // Join comment replies to comments
  public function replies() {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
  }

  public function scopeByArticle($query, Article $article)
  {
      return $query->where('article_id', $article->id);   
  }
}
```

I would prefer the first approach as you have more control when you use the eager loading.

The GET method I not supported, because you probably didn't define the Ajax route for the GET method in routes/web.php or routes/api.php.

In the controller, I'd do something like this:

```
ArticleController extends Controller {


 public function show( $slug ) {
    // Single article
    $article     = Article::firstWhere( 'slug', $slug );
    $old_article = Article::where( 'id', '<', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->first();
    $new_article = Article::where( 'id', '>', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'ASC' )->first();

    // Comments
    $commentsQuery  = $article->comments()->where('approved', 1)->with(['comments', 'comments.recursiveReplies']);
    // Count of all comments per Article including replies
    $comments_count = Comment::byArticle($article)->count();

    // If infinite scroll, paginate comments (to be loaded one page per scroll),
    // Else show them all 

    if (boolval($this->is_infinitescroll)) {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate($this->comments_per_page);
    } else {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->get();
    }

    return view( 'themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single',
                 array_merge( $this->data, [
                   'categories'        => $this->article_categories,
                   'article'           => $article,
                   'old_article'       => $old_article,
                   'new_article'       => $new_article,
                   'comments'          => $comments,
                   'comments_count'    => $comments_count,
                   'comments_per_page' => $this->comments_per_page,
                   'tagline'           => $article->title,
                   'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
                 ] )
    );
  }

}
```

Now, instead of using the `replies` relationship in your blade/ajax response, use the `recursiveReplies`.

Also, instead of `Comment::create( $comment )` use `$comment->replies()->create($comment);` This way you will never have an orphan comment saved.

Comment: Where is the `recursiveReplies` variable used?

Comment: Also: The `$comments_count` variable, in `comments.blade.php` *does not* count the replies.

Comment: Also: when I enable AJAX comment-loading, I get the error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` for the route: _load_comments_.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, I've edited the post and added more details.

Comment: The line `$commentsQuery  = $article->comments()->where('approved', 1)->with(['comments', 'comments.recursiveReplies']);` throws an error: `Call to undefined method App\Models\Article::comments()`

Comment: Yes, you need a HasMany relationship in the Article model to the Comment model.

Comment: How would that look? And why? :)

Comment: `public function comments() {
   return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'article_id', 'id');
}`. 
You need it for many reasons: it's safer to use the creation through a relationship, safer to validate, retrieve, count, etc.